# Swift SqLite Setup

Tags: ios, swift, sqlite

Im making an application for IOS 9, using swift, and my application will consist of using a database. I searched on the internet and set up a SqLite database and am using the Firefox add on to have a GUI to view it. I make a Xcode project and as many tutorials said to do I went to my Build Phases > Link Binary With Libraries and searched for libsqlite3.0.dylib but I only found libsqlite3.tbd and libsqlite3.0.tbd . I said ok and clicked on libsqlite3.tbd hoping that it wouldnt matter, but I got stuck at the next step of using sqlite in IOS.  I had to

```
    #import <sqlite3.h>
```

but the thing was that i would get an error when ever that happened. I just need some step by step instructions on how to get my SqLite database to start working!!! I can't find anything on the web that isn't using IOS 7 and adding libsqlite3.dylib to their build phase. Please help!!

Comment: Better be using CoreData rather then SQLLite . I am not sure what are the requirements but CoreData is better approach unless you really need something SQLLite provides and and available in CoreData.

Comment: ya you did on correct way , in Swift the complier default take the class name, continue your work

Comment: is core data available to multiple users? can more than two people add to the core data and view it?

Answer (score 0):

You may try the following:

When expand Link Binary and hit + , then click 'Add other', when the window pops up hit CTRL+Shift + G. In the Go to folder field put /usr/lib -> Go and you will find 'libsqlite3.dylib'

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use a Swift SQLite wrapper such as https://github.com/groue/GRDB.swift or https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Swift then Here is an easy solution.

Step 1: Import SQLite

```
import SQLite3
```

Step 2: Create and Open a database file

```
let fileURL = try! FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false)
    .appendingPathComponent("YourFileName.sqlite")
if sqlite3_open(fileURL.path, &db) != SQLITE_OK {
        print("error opening database")
    }
```

Step 4: Create a Table

```
if sqlite3_exec(db, "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Heroes (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, name TEXT, powerrank INTEGER)", nil, nil, nil) != SQLITE_OK {
        let errmsg = String(cString: sqlite3_errmsg(db)!)
        print("error creating table: \(errmsg)")
    }
```

Step 5: Insert Values

```
 var stmt: OpaquePointer?

        let queryString = "INSERT INTO Heroes (name, powerrank) VALUES (?,?)"

        if sqlite3_prepare(db, queryString, -1, &stmt, nil) != SQLITE_OK{
            let errmsg = String(cString: sqlite3_errmsg(db)!)
            print("error preparing insert: \(errmsg)")
            return
        }

        if sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 1, name, -1, nil) != SQLITE_OK{
            let errmsg = String(cString: sqlite3_errmsg(db)!)
            print("failure binding name: \(errmsg)")
            return
        }

        if sqlite3_bind_int(stmt, 2, (powerRanking! as NSString).intValue) != SQLITE_OK{
            let errmsg = String(cString: sqlite3_errmsg(db)!)
            print("failure binding name: \(errmsg)")
            return
        }

        if sqlite3_step(stmt) != SQLITE_DONE {
            let errmsg = String(cString: sqlite3_errmsg(db)!)
            print("failure inserting hero: \(errmsg)")
            return
        }
```

By following these steps you can easily insert some rows in your table. For other operations like, reading visit this nice step by step guide - **[Swift SQLite Tutorial](https://www.simplifiedios.net/swift-sqlite-tutorial/)**.